# how to print values for multiple keys in a hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hashmap that hold k,v  like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> total=new HashMap<>();
```

this is how im populating the map:(in a for loop from some result of db table)

```
total.put(rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("name"));
```

Now, some keys have multiple values, I want to print for each key: key and value. so it will look something like this:

```
123   john

123   tom

123   jack

234   terry

234   jeniffer

345   jacob

555   sara
```

how can I do this please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` (and, in fact, all classes implementing `Map`) only stores one value per key.

Quoting the Javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

To store "multiple" values per key, you need a value type which is able to store multiple values, e.g. a `Collection` like a `List` or `Set`, so your map type might be `Map<String, List<String>>`.

It's a little bit clumsy to manage: you basically have to check if there is already a collection associated with a key, add an empty one if not, and then add to the collection:

```
// Instead of:
map.put(key, value);

// ...you'd need something like:
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
  map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get(key).add(value);
```

Alternatively, there are libraries like Guava which provide the [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), which does more like what you describe directly.

Comment: i added the line that show how im populating the map, could you show me what do i need to write?